# Is there a #between? for numbers in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I was wondering if I simply cannot find a `between` method for numbers in Crystal.

In Ruby, there's the `Comparable#between?` method which can (among others) compare two numeric values (my specific case).

**Background**: I want to achieve a not-between solution without using

```
variable < 2 || variable > 5
```

I tried `5.between(2,5)` and `5.between?(2,5)` but all I got was a compilation error:

> Error in line 1: undefined method 'between?' for Int32

I ended up with extending the number structure:

```
struct Number
  def between?(a, b)
    self <=> a >= 0 && self <=> b <= 0
  end
end
```

**Question 2**: Is my solution above a feasible one? If not, suggestions are welcomed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In crystal you can write `2 <= variable <= 5`, which is easier to read and gives you greater control over inclusivity/exclusivity at each end of the range.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the question with my intent: I want the between to use it as a not-between check later.

Comment: `!(2 <= variable <= 5)`. Or just `variable < 2 || variable > 5`. Your second solution is not really needed, just do two comparisons, it's much more clear than `between`, which hides the information about inclusive/exclusive comparision.

Comment: Another option is [`Range#includes?`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/latest/Range.html#includes?(value)-instance-method): `(2..5).includes?(variable).`But still, I think comparison operators reads much better

Answer (score 0):

From a deleted answer but I still like it:

You can use a similar method [Range#includes?](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.25.1/Range.html#includes?(value)-instance-method) (or #covers).